# How create imported class object in typescirpt?

Tags: typescript, amd

```
interface IModal {
    widgetNames: KnockoutObservableArray<string>;
    widgets: KnockoutObservableArray<IWidget>;
}
```

one web.d.ts file where i declare module

```
declare module "modules/dialog/modal" {
    var theModal: IModal;
    export = theModal;
}

class modal implements IModal {
   widgetNames: KnockoutObservableArray<string>;
   widgets: KnockoutObservableArray<IWidget>;

 constructor() {
    this.widgetNames= ko.observable<string>(['widget1','widget2'])
 }
}
export = modal;
```

Class index is where i want to import modal.ts file and create new object.
my problem is that when import modal.ts then unable to create object. Typescript not compiler index.ts file here  "new modal()"

```
import modal = require('modules/dialog/modal');
class index{
constructor(){
  var_modal = new modal();//problem here, unable to create modal. not compiled by typescript compiler; i don't want to use singleton pattern;

 }
}
export = index;
```

solution is import that: this work fine

```
import modal = require('./modal');//modal path
class index{
constructor(){
  var_modal = new modal();

 }
}
export = index
```

this work fine, but if i want to change ('./modal')  path: "../../widgets/personInfo/viewmodel"
after rebuild solution, visual studio shot an erros:

Unable to resolve external module "../../widgets/personInfo/viewmodel"
Build: Module cannot be aliased to a non-module type.
Invalid 'new' expression

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you shouldn't need :

```
declare module "modules/dialog/modal" {
    var theModal: IModal;
    export = theModal;
}
```

if you have a file `fooModal.ts` as :

```
class modal implements IModal {
   widgetNames: KnockoutObservableArray<string>;
   widgets: KnockoutObservableArray<IWidget>;

 constructor() {
    this.widgetNames= ko.observable<string>(['widget1','widget2'])
 }
}
export = modal;
```

You can simply do:

```
import modal = require('./fooModal');
class index{
constructor(){
  var_modal = new modal();//problem here, unable to create modal. not compiled; i don't want to use singleton pattern;

 }
}
export = index;
```